# How to change supported Refresh rate in Linux display Driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In my Linux frame buffer driver,it supports below resolutions and refresh rate.

`cat /sys/class/graphics/fb1/modes` command gives below supports

```
D:1600x900p-59
D:720x400p-70
V:640x480p-60
V:640x480p-75
V:800x600p-60
V:800x600p-75
V:1024x768p-60
V:1024x768p-75
V:1280x1024p-75
S:1152x864p-75
S:1280x1024p-60
D:1600x900p-59
```

### My question is

where these values are initialized and supported in driver; Especially refresh rate  (eg : 59,70,60) Because i want to support different refresh rate  `D:1600x900p-60` instead of `D:1600x900p-59`.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To chose a mode listed in supported resolution type the following in terminal:

```
xrandr -s 1600x900 -r 59
```

But since the mode you want is not listed use this to define a new mode :

```
xrandr --newmode $(gtf 1600 900 60 | sed -ne 's/"//g;s/ Modeline //p')
```

and then add it to your list ( I chose *Custom* as a name of this mode)

```
xrandr --addmode Custom 1600x900_60.00
```

and then

```
xrandr -s 1600x900 -r 60
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. In my embedded Linux, xrandr is not supported. By the way, I want to add support in the OS binary itself by default. For this I need to add support in the video driver. But don't have clear idea where these supports to be added exactly. Can you clear this thing?

Comment: You can find these configurations in the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.